# PHP SimpleTest - Using multiple test cases

Tags: php, unit-testing, simpletest

I have been trying to use SimpleTest to begin unit testing my code, I have a working test that works on its own, but I want to use a single directory that will contain a range of tests, and a TestSuite will run all of those tests, my working test is:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../simpletest/autorun.php');

define("ROOT",'/var/web/trunk/');
require_once('/usr/share/log4php/src/main/php/Logger.php');

class TestBayCrazy extends UnitTestCase { 

  function testDatabase () {
    require_once(ROOT.'includes/libs.inc.php');
    $database = new Database();
    $this->assertTrue($database->connected == TRUE);

    $database = new Database('a','b','c','d','e');
    $this->assertTrue($database->connected == FALSE);

    $database = null;
  }

}
```

My TestSuite is:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/simpletest/autorun.php');

define("ROOT",'/var/web/trunk/');
require_once('/usr/share/log4php/src/main/php/Logger.php');


class AllTests extends TestSuite {
  function AllTests() {
    $this->TestSuite('All Tests');
    $this->addFile('tests/testDatabase.php');
    $this->addFile('tests/testSession.php');
    $this->addFile('tests/testValidate.php');
  }
}
```

But this returns the following when run:

```
2011/10/05 12:37:47 [error] 3242#0: *309 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:
Call to a member function getDumper() on a non-object in 
/var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/test_case.php on line 316 PHP Stack trace: PHP   
1. simpletest_autorun() /var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/autorun.php:0 PHP   
2. run_local_tests() /var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/autorun.php:28 PHP   
3. TestSuite-run() /var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/autorun.php:52 PHP
4. TestSuite->run() /var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/test_case.php:563 PHP
5. TestSuite->run() /var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/test_case.php:563 PHP
6. TestSession->testSession() /var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/test_case.php:559 PHP
7. UnitTestCase->assertIsA() /var/web/trunk/private/tests/testSession.php:10 PHP
8. SimpleTestCase->assert() /var/web/trunk/private/simpletest/unit_tester.php:110"
while reading response header from upstream, client: 0.0.0.0, 
server: example.com, request: "GET /private/unittest.php HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "0.0.0.0
```

So, what on earth am I doing wrong? I've only found examples on how to do a testSuite, not how a test needs to be different when it's a member of a suite, rather than stand alone (may be down to my lack of familiarity with the language of unit testing).

Comment: We switched from SimpleTest to PHPUnit because SimpleTest is abandoned and PHPUnit works similarly to the other xUnit projects. I highly recommend you do the same, especially since you're just starting out and won't need to rewrite old tests. We rewrote the old tests, and it was still worth it. We never looked back...

Comment: I agree with David, if you have a choice use PHPUnit. I've run into a number of problems with SimpleTest's mock objects.

Comment: Very old, but I did switch to PHPUnit in the end! A steeper learning curve in some ways, but nobody can say it doesn't work as it's designed to! Well, I hope not! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually use GroupTest instead of a Suite

```
$dbgroup = new GroupTest("running database tests");
$dbgroup->addTestFile('tests/testDatabase.php');
$dbgroup->run(new HtmlReporter());
```

It does the job well enough...

Comment: Thanks @case, I dropped SimpleTest in the end, but I'm marking your answer as correct, as it makes sense and I trust you! :-)